# Spring Entity Manager cannot be initiated : Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

As a developer
I would like to develop a Spring JPA to access Oracle 9i database to fetch records via stored procedures
I want to connect to the database via application.yml but I initiate the project with the configuration file application.properties

I declare this in  application.properties

```
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect
spring.jpa.database=default
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true 
spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect
```

and  in application.yml

```
 jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none

      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
        implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
    properties:
      hibernate:
        proc.param_null_passing: true
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect
    show-sql: true
```

When it comes to execution, it raises the following exceptions

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

Would you please tell me what other ways for me to modify the class or configuration file? 
Here is my code of Configuration Class :

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
         entityManagerFactoryRef = "productEntityManagerFactory",
         transactionManagerRef = "productTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.pccw.ruby.repository"})

public class DBConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.pccw.ruby.domain");

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.proc.param_null_passing", new Boolean(true));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Here is my oracle database version :

Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.6.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.proc.param_null_passing", new Boolean(true));
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.class.getName());
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect");
```

Try setting it here.

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.pccw.ruby.domain.PcLookUp

Comment: Should I name the table into my model ?

Comment: Add @Id to com.pccw.ruby.domain.PcLookUp entity class

Comment: ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor